# Different hashing results in Dart vs PHP code

Tags: php, api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get this working in flutter and i cant get the same outcome. 
My php code prints a diffrent hash then my flutter code. Is it posible to do this in a flutter app?

i have tried to achieve this by running this flutter code. But after 5 hours of reading i gave up and created a stack overflow account.

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; // for the utf8.encode method
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() {
  var api = 'https://app.repricer.nl';
  var endpoint = '/api/v1/channels/all.json';
  var method = 'GET';
  var public_key = '';
  var private_key = '';
  var data = '';


  var ms = (new DateTime.now()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  var timestamp = ms / 1000;

  var hash_string = public_key + '|' + method + '|' + endpoint + '|' + data + '|' + timestamp.toString();

  var key = utf8.encode(private_key);
  var bytes = utf8.encode(hash_string);

  var hmacSha256 = new Hmac(sha512, key); // HMAC-SHA256
  var digest = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);

  print(digest);
}
```

This is the PHP code that i want to convert to flutter:

```
$api = 'https://app.repricer.nl';
$endpoint = '/api/v1/channels/all.json';
$method = 'GET';
$public_key = '';
$private_key = '';


// Generate the CURL headers to authenticate our request
$headers = generateHash($public_key, $private_key, $method, $endpoint, $data);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$api.$endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);

function generateHash($public_key, $private_key, $method, $endpoint, $data)
{
    $timestamp = date("U");
    $hash_string = array($public_key,$method,$endpoint,$data,$timestamp);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha512',implode('|',$hash_string),$private_key);    
    print ($hash);
    return array('X-Auth: '.$public_key, 'X-Hash: '.$hash, 'X-Date: '.$timestamp);
}
```

I expect the output is the same exept from the timestamp. But i ran it in the same second and it are 2 completly diffrent outcomes.

Comment: Give us some example input and output.

Comment: Demian - please check my answer and let's discuss if You still getting different results

Comment: Yes your right, it is the same. Sorry for this.

Comment: I checked it again. The diffrent output is becouse php give a timestamp without comma and flutter with comma. I added a .round to my code and now its fixed.

Comment: @DemianOttema no need for sorry. it’s totally correct to ask question. and it’s not trivial question, cause it shows how to port the code from one lang to another and how to check results.

Comment: @DemianOttema I recommend to use toInt() since rounding is different math operation. toInt cuts out floating part when round does rounding depending on float part.

Comment: Thats true, otherwise the api can give a error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is correct.**

**Small fix** is just replacing:

```
ms / 1000   to   (ms / 1000).toInt()
```

I don't see other flaw in Your code.

I've came to that answer after doing test run with constant timestamp parameter: **1572731120**

PHP:

```
$timestamp = 1572731120; //date("U");
$hash_string = array($public_key,$method,$endpoint,$data,$timestamp);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha512',implode('|',$hash_string),$private_key);
```

Dart

```
  var ms = (new DateTime.now()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  var timestamp = 1572731120;//(ms / 1000).toInt(); 

  var hash_string = public_key + '|' + method + '|' + endpoint + '|' + data + '|' + timestamp.toString();

  var key = utf8.encode(private_key);
  var bytes = utf8.encode(hash_string);

  var hmacSha256 = new Hmac(sha512, key); // HMAC-SHA256
  var digest = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);
```

which proves that results are equal:

[image: hmac hashing comparison php and dart]